# How can I get the list of all member_action methods defined ActiveAdmin resource class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm making a script in rails 4.1 that is reading all the ActiveAdmin resource classes along with their member_action methods, but how can I get the additional defined methods inside the class ? 
The goal of that script is to get all the resources with the methods defined in the class in order to set the admin user permissions in the database

```
def get_permissions
    skip_resources = [ 'dashboard.rb' ];
    default_actions = [ 'create', 'read', 'update', 'delete' ];
    resources = Dir.new("#{Rails.root}/app/admin").entries

    all_resources = {}
    resources.each do |resource|
        if resource =~ /.rb/ && (not skip_resources.include? resource)
            resource_class = resource.gsub(".rb","")
            # resource_obj = resource_class.camelize.constantize.new
            all_resources[resource_class] = default_actions #TODO: merge with the defined in class methods
        end
    end
    all_resources
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "additional defined methods"? Are you referring to ActiveAdmin `member_action` and `collection_action` or custom controller actions?

Answer (score 1):

This rake task outputs all defined actions for both resource and pages, but it does require loading Rails and the ActiveAdmin configuration.

Also available as a gist: [active_admin_actions.rake](https://gist.github.com/zorab47/7b762a3bec30355389bf)

```
task :active_admin_actions => :environment do
    skip_resources = [ 'Dashboard' ]

    namespace = ActiveAdmin.application.namespace(:admin)

    pages     = namespace.resources.select { |r| r.is_a? ActiveAdmin::Page }
    resources = namespace.resources.select { |r| r.respond_to? :resource_class }

    resource_actions =
      resources.each_with_object({}) do |resource, actions|
        resource_name = resource.resource_class.name

        if !skip_resources.include? resource_name
          actions[resource_name] = resource.defined_actions
          actions[resource_name].concat resource.member_actions.map { |action| action.name }
          actions[resource_name].concat resource.collection_actions.map { |action| action.name }
        end
      end

    puts resource_actions.inspect

    page_actions =
      pages.each_with_object({}) do |page, actions|
        page_name = page.name

        if !skip_resources.include? page_name
          actions[page_name] = page.page_actions + [:index]
        end
      end

    puts page_actions.inspect
end
```